# Unbounded derivatives of real differentiable functions

Tags: functions, derivatives

I'm interested in the way values at specific points affect the overall structure of a real differentiable function. So suppose that for the real function $f$ 
$(1)\space f$ is infinitely differentiable for $x \ge 0$ 
$(2)\space f(0) = 0$ and $f^n(0) = 0$ for all $n=1,2,3...$ 
$(3)$ for some $a>0, f(a) \neq 0$

Then by the Taylor remainder theorem, there exists some $b: 0 < b < a$,
such that the sequence of derivatives $\lvert f^n(b) \rvert$ of $f$ at $b$,
is unbounded as $n=1,2,3...$ (otherwise $f(a) = 0$).

My question is: must the sequence of derivatives $f^n(x)$ for $n=1,2,3,...$ be unbounded 
 for all $0 < x \le b$? Is there a relevant theorem or a counterexample?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Consider a [smooth transition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#Smooth_transition_functions).

Answer (score 1):

Think of the function
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
e^{-1}, & \text{if } 1<|x|\\
e^{-1/x^2},&\text{if }0\leq|x|\leq 1\\
0,&\text{if }x=0\;,
\end{cases},
$$
which has all derivatives vanishing at zero.

This function has, for $|x|\in (0,1)$, derivative $f'(x)=\frac{2e^{-1/x^2}}{x^3}$, which is bounded by $2/e$.